# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running following simple python3 script on Windows11:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'
service = Service(executable_path='C:\\ProgramFiles\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe')
webC = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)
```

I am getting the flowing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/NNs/CrawlerStarter/selenium_test.py", line 8, in <module>
    webC = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\crawler\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\crawler\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\crawler\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 276, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\crawler\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 369, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\crawler\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 434, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\crawler\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 207, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 


Process finished with exit code 1
```

**There is not error message to tell what's going wrong**, and I have tried related solutions that could found in Google, such as setting Path in System Environment. But it's still occurred same exception. Also, I had the same problem when I switched to Firefox

Here are my versions:

```
python: 3.8.13
selenium: 4.4.0
google chrome: 104.0.5112.81
chromedriver: 104.0.5112.79
```

Thank you for answering my question!

Comment: When `options` and `executable_path` have the same driver path, why to have both in the webdriver parameters. With my limited knowledge, I am unclear of this? Also, did you try `webdriver_manager`?

Comment: @AnandGautam Thank you for your reply. Specifying both is a bit redundant, but that's probably not the problem. Even if I just set `executable_path`, the error message will still be the same(empty message string). I've tried the `webdriver_manager`, but the results are the same.